# How to install Apache on OmniOS

Tags: apache, package, omnios, pkgsrc

I am attempting to install Apache on OmniOS. I followed the instructions here: option 2  https://wiki.openindiana.org/oi/3.+Installing+software+and+package+management

**Ran the command:**

- `echo $PATH` results in `/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`
- `curl https://pkgsrc.joyent.com/packages/SmartOS/bootstrap/bootstrap-2016Q4-x86_64.tar.gz | gtar -zxpf - -C /`
- `pkgin -y update`
- `pkgin -y install apache-2.4.6` resulted in the messages `Calculating dependencies...done` and then `nothing to do`

I can not find the apache service or configuration directory as they are described here: https://docs.joyent.com/public-cloud/instances/infrastructure/images/smartos/apache

- `/opt/local/etc/httpd`    The configuration directory for Apache
- `svcs pkgsrc/apache` Checking service for Apache

**Server Info:**

- `uname -v` results in `omnios-r151026-d9b45886bd`
- Running x86
- Also running SunONE webserver

Though incomplete, my commands did make a change. My Perl scripts can no longer find DBI.

Why does the Apache install say there is `nothing to do`? What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

- Ran `which apache2` resulted in `no apache2`
- Ran `pkgin list` to list all installed packages. Only apache
  reference is `apache-maven-3.5.4`
- Ran `find . -name '*apache*'` in the following directories:

  - `\etc` nothing
  - `\opt` found:

    - vim, el, and elc files in `SUNWspro`
    - `org-apache-tools-ant-module` files and folder in `netbeans/3.5V11/modules/patches`
    - `apache` folder in `SUNWwbsvr/plugins/java/samples/webapps/jstl/src/org` which contains java files
    - vim, tag, el and elc files in `sfw` --- also an `apache` folder in `sfw` which contains readme/bash type files for apache/php and one so file
    - `apache-maven-3.5.4` files/folders in `local`
    - `org-apache-xml-resolver*` files in `sunstudio12.1`
  - '\usr' found:

    - 2 vims in `share/vim/vim80/syntax`
    - `apache-fcgi.conf` in `lib/python2.7/vendor-packages/cherrypy/scaffold`
  - '\var' nothing

As far as I can tell, the binaries have not been installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running `pkgin -y install apache-2` and it worked. It installed `apache-2.4.3`. Perhaps `apache-2.4.6` does not exist in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

This mean apache is already installed on the Linux system. To run below command which will tell the location of the system binary.

> which apache2

for the configuration folder look for below directory:

> /etc/apache2